# Вендорные префиксы для Safari

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка, flexbox, safari

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить неработающий flex на сафари.

Во всех браузерах все отлично работает, а в сафари что-то не получается.
Версия Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2)

Блоки не смещаются вниз совсем, все 6 штук в строку располагаются и, соответственно, появляется горизонтальная прокрутка.

Как "подружить" стили с safari?
[image: На первом рис - от, что отображается в сафари][image: на втором - как должно быть]

После прогона через автопрефиксер я получила такой код, который не дает нужного результата:

```css
      <!-- Стили для меню картинками-->
.container {all: initial;}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-item-align: center;
     align-self: center;
}

.choice {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url(Plan.jpg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.justify-content-between { 
  -webkit-box-pack: center; 
      -ms-flex-pack: center; 
          justify-content: center;
 } 

 .flex-wrap {
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
 }


.container { width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; 
   inherit: none;} 

 .d-flex { display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex; }
 
 
 break{
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 100%;  
      flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0px; 
  height: 0px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
 
  @media screen and (max-width: 1505) .line-break {  width: 100%;}
 
  @media screen and (
   max-width: 1488) {
    .line-break {
  width: 0%;}
  .container {inherit: none; 
   width: 40%;
   max-width: 1200 px;
   margin: 0 auto; } 
}
 
  @media screen and (max-width: 1100) {
  .container {inherit: none;
   width: 95%;}
   nav {-ms-flex-line-pack:  center;align-content:  center;}
   .wrapper {
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-box-orient:vertical;
-webkit-box-direction:normal;
    -ms-flex-direction:column;
        flex-direction:column;
  
 -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  
     -ms-grid-row-align: center;
  
     align-self: center;
}
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 1487) {
  break {display: none;}
 }
 
 
 @media screen and (min-width: 1488 and max-width: 2193) {
  section: nth-child(3n) 
   after;
 }
      
      <!--Конец стилей меню-картинками -->
```

```html
<div class="container">
          <nav class="wrapper d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
            <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/database.html';">
              <figure>
                <h3><a href="">Последнее обновление</a></h3>
                <br>
                <img src="Today-final.jpg" alt="Все квартиры за сегодня"> <figcaption>Адреса
                  и описания / Все варианты за сегодня</figcaption> </figure>
            </section>
            <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/area.html';">
              <figure>
                <h3 class="select"><a href="">По районам СПб</a></h3>
                <br>
                <img src="Metro-distr-final.jpg" alt="Квартиры по районам и метро">
                <figcaption>Длительная аренда по районам и метро</figcaption> </figure>
            </section>
            <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/sut.html';">
              <section class="line-break"></section>
              <figure>
                <h3><a href="">Посуточные квартиры</a></h3>
                <br>
                <img src="Sutochno-final.jpg" alt="Аренда на несколько дней"> <figcaption>
                  Квартиры в аренду на короткие сроки</figcaption> </figure>
            </section>
            <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/database.html';">
              <figure>
                <h3><a href="">Однокомнатные квартиры</a></h3>
                <br>
                <img src="1KKV-final.jpg" alt="Снять однокомнатную квартиру в СПб">
                <figcaption>Снять однокомнатную квартиру в СПб</figcaption> </figure>
            </section>
            <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/area.html';">
              <figure>
                <h3><a href="">Двухкомнатные квартиры</a></h3>
                <br>
                <img src="2KKV-final.jpg" alt="Снять двухкомнатную квартиру в СПб">
                <figcaption>Снять двухкомнатную квартиру в СПб </figcaption> </figure>
            </section>
            <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/sut.html';">
              <figure>
                <h3><a href="">Трехкомнатные квартиры и более</a></h3>
                <br>
                <img src="3KKV-final.jpg" alt="Снять трех-, четырехкомнатную квартиру в СПб">
                <figcaption> Снять трехкомнатную, четырехкомнатную ...</figcaption>
              </figure>
            </section>
          </nav>
        </div>
```

Помогите, чем можете, люди добрые!

Comment: Покажите скриншот ожидаемого результата (из другого браузера), скриншот из сафари и версию сафари (а то я не совсем уверен, что пойму код правильно без скриншотов)

Comment: Последняя версия Safari для Windows вышла ШЕСТЬ лет назад, очень устарела и не имеет никакой поддержки flex. Просто забейте на этот браузер и ничего не делайте, его никто не использует (кроме вас)

Comment: А! Хорошо, если так. Я сейчас проверю в эмуляторах мобильных устройств. Идея была в том, чтобы в сафари на мобильниках все было адаптивно.

Comment: А ещё в любом случае префиксы у вас не те (если точнее, они слишком старые), вместо `display: -webkit-box;` должно быть `display: -webkit-flex;` и остальное тоже требует исправления

Comment: Автопрефиксер, значит, подвел. А где можно почитать об этом подробнее? Я на caniuse.com сегодня впервые зашла, еще не поняла что к чему...

Comment: Ну не знаю, первый попавшийся из гугла автопрефиксер https://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/ вроде бы нормально всё расставляет с фильтром `Safari >= 7` https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb04R.png

Comment: Именно им я и пользовалась. Про фильтры не знаю ничего пока... Ушла в гугл спрашивать. Спасибо Вам! Если оформите все написанное из комментов в ответ, я смогу выбрать его лучшим.

Comment: Про фильтры в [документации модуля browserlist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist), который и используется этим автопрефиксером

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) - участника комментариев к вопросу удалось добиться приемлемого вида даже на десктопном safari для windows.

Вендорные префиксы, полученные на сайте https://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/ **с фильтром Safari >= 7**,
плюс найденные на просторах сети свойства для выравнивания по горизонтали в этом проблемном браузере:

```css
{
    text-align:-moz-center;
    text-align:-webkit-center;
}
```

практически решили мою проблему. Осталась задача по адаптации под сафари псевдоклассов, но это решительно не критично, просто перфекционист во мне проснулся.